# how to search within a p tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, search, filter

I want to search a `<p>` with plain javascript but I can't figure out how to. I have tried googling it and I have scoured stackOverflow, but I can't figure out how to search inside of a `<p>`.

```
<input id="search">
<p>Some text content I want</p>
<script>
  //script to search the above "p"
</script>
```

I want the javascript to style the matches it finds.

Here is a [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLodoycb/) of what I've got.

**SUMMARY:**

- You type in a query
- the JS looks for a match

  - if match is found: highlight the match

Comment: **EDIT** I would like to make it so that the java-script highlights the word found

Comment: hi, bro, you can using one id in you <p> and call for jquery or javascript:
<p id="pname">hi bro!</p>
call:
javacript: document.getElementById('pname')
JQ: $('#pname').html()

Comment: here is a js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gLodoycb/

Comment: Don't add "solved" to your title; instead, accept the answer that solved your problem.  Thanks!

Comment: ok NobodyNada (:

Comment: And please dont make all your comments bold, you're not that special ;)

Comment: @Martijn ok, I deleted the bold comment

Comment: -**can an admin close this thread?**-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an [answer](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/973gdh8g/). **THANKS TO ALL WHO ANSWERED MY QUESTION!**

```
    $(function() {

  // the input field
  var $input = $("input[type='search']"),
    // clear button
    $clearBtn = $("button[data-search='clear']"),
    // prev button
    $prevBtn = $("button[data-search='prev']"),
    // next button
    $nextBtn = $("button[data-search='next']"),
    // the context where to search
    $content = $(".content"),
    // jQuery object to save <mark> elements
    $results,
    // the class that will be appended to the current
    // focused element
    currentClass = "current",
    // top offset for the jump (the search bar)
    offsetTop = 50,
    // the current index of the focused element
    currentIndex = 0;

  /**
   * Jumps to the element matching the currentIndex
   */
  function jumpTo() {
    if ($results.length) {
      var position,
        $current = $results.eq(currentIndex);
      $results.removeClass(currentClass);
      if ($current.length) {
        $current.addClass(currentClass);
        position = $current.offset().top - offsetTop;
        window.scrollTo(0, position);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Searches for the entered keyword in the
   * specified context on input
   */
  $input.on("input", function() {
    var searchVal = this.value;
    $content.unmark({
      done: function() {
        $content.mark(searchVal, {
          separateWordSearch: true,
          done: function() {
            $results = $content.find("mark");
            currentIndex = 0;
            jumpTo();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  /**
   * Clears the search
   */
  $clearBtn.on("click", function() {
    $content.unmark();
    $input.val("").focus();
  });

  /**
   * Next and previous search jump to
   */
  $nextBtn.add($prevBtn).on("click", function() {
    if ($results.length) {
      currentIndex += $(this).is($prevBtn) ? -1 : 1;
      if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = $results.length - 1;
      }
      if (currentIndex > $results.length - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      jumpTo();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function myfunction(ctrl) {
var TextInsideP = ctrl.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
}
```

Your `p` tag contents are now inside the variable `TextInsideP`, and you can do with them whatever you want.

Comment: can this highlight the word it found?

Comment: No, all it does is store the contents of the `p` tag in a variable. If you need to highlight a certain word you can add code to this function to search the variable and look for a specific string.

Answer (score 0):

You can first take get the contents of the first p element in the #search element and then execute the search thusly.  Will return the string position for the searched element or -1 if not found.

```
var text = document.querySelector('#search p')[0].innerHTML;
var n = text.search("text to find");

if (n !== -1) {
  // Found!
} else {
  // Not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching for a specific word within the 'p' tag, you have to grab it with a selector. then you have to split the string of words, loop through them and search using indexOf (see below)

```js
    var input = document.getElementById('search');
    input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
          var val = input.value;
          searchExactMatch(val);
          searchPartialMatch(val);
    })
    var p = document.getElementById('test');
    var text = p.innerHTML;
    var splits = text.split(' ');
    function searchExactMatch(value) {
      var word = value;
      var index = splits.indexOf(word);
      if (index > -1) {
       console.log('full match with: ', splits[index]);
      }
    }
    function searchPartialMatch(value) {
      var word = value;
      for (var t = 0; t < splits.length; t++) {
        var split = splits[t];
        if (split.indexOf(word) > -1) {
          console.log('the typed string is a partial match with: ', split);
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<p id="test">text goes here</p>
<input id="search" />
```

Comment: is it possible to make "var word" = (what was typed into the input)?

Comment: @DiscoNuggetDevelopment see above edits - does that answer your question?

Comment: pretty well; but I would like it to highlight the match instead of showing it in the console

Answer (score 0):

You can access texts between open and close tags using `document.getElementsBytagName('tagName')`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci[ng] velit, sed quia non numquam [do] eius modi tempora inci[di]dunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    //document.write(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText); //Old text from the tag <p>
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText = "This works great."; //new text inside tag <p>.

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to highlight stuff then you need to replace some content with another.
My idea is the following: making yourSearchWord bold:

```
let paragraph = document.getElementById('idHere').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('idHere').innerHTML = paragraph.split('yourSearchWord').join('<b>yourSearchWord</b>');
```

Comment: **how do I apply that to my input and p tag?**

Comment: exactly that. What is your p tag ID?

Comment: it has a class="content" no id (should I add an id?)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that will highlight the `p` elements for you when the value typed in the input matches the string in a `p` element exactly.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('p');
var HIGHLIGHT_STYLE_PREFIX = '<span style="background-color:yellow">';
var HIGHLIGHT_STYLE_SUFFIX = '</span>';

document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('input', highlightMatches);

function highlightMatches() {
  var queryTerm = this.value.trim();
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].childNodes.forEach(function(currentValue) {
      if (currentValue.data === queryTerm) {
        elements[i].innerHTML = HIGHLIGHT_STYLE_PREFIX + elements[i].innerHTML + HIGHLIGHT_STYLE_SUFFIX;
      } else {
        if (elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(HIGHLIGHT_STYLE_SUFFIX) > -1) {
          elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(HIGHLIGHT_STYLE_PREFIX, '').replace(HIGHLIGHT_STYLE_SUFFIX, '');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="search" />

<p>Sed ut perspiciatis</p>, unde
<p>omnis</p> iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.
<p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia</p>
<p>omnis</p>
<p>consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi</p>

nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci[ng] velit, sed quia non numquam [do] eius modi tempora inci[di]dunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat
<p>voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem</p> ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae

<p>consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Looks like it's working to me when I run the code snippet.

Comment: @DiscoNuggetDevelopment You need to update your question because requirements weren't very clear. I THINK this is what youre trying to achieve. The script will hightlight the `p` if the entire term searched is matched

Comment: this snippet doesn't do anything

Comment: @DiscoNuggetDevelopment Yes it does. You're probably entering the text slightly differently. It has to be exact, meaning it is case-sensitive.  Also the text you entered has to be in a `p` element.

Comment: @DiscoNuggetDevelopment I updated the code 1 last time so now only the words within the `p` element will be highlighted instead of the entire `p`. Try entering "omnis" or "Sed ut perspiciatis" to see how it works

Comment: @DiscoNuggetDevelopment could you please mark the answer as accepted if this solves your problem. Thanks.

Comment: it didn't actually solve my problem but it helped. so thanks